# how to segue from 2nd button on MKannotation?

Tags: swift, mkannotation

I have added a left button to my `MKAnnotation`. I want it to show this as well as the right button and images I have set below.  This code below is showing both buttons but only recognizing the right button click to my segue for `NewEntry`. How can specify the `calloutAccessoryControl` to recognize the left button tapped, as well as the right button tapped, and add the additional segue from the left button to 'left detail' for my `LeftButtonDetailViewController`?

Here is my code:

```
//MARK: - MKMapview Delegate
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        guard let subtitle = annotation.subtitle! else { return nil }

        if (annotation is SpecimenAnnotation) {
            if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(subtitle) {
                return annotationView
            } else {
                let currentAnnotation = annotation as! SpecimenAnnotation
                let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: subtitle)

                switch subtitle {
                case "Uncategorized":
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "IconUncategorized")
                case "Documentaries":
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "IconDocumentaries")
                default:
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "IconUncategorized")
                }

                annotationView.enabled = true
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                let detailDisclosure1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
                let detailDisclosure2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.InfoDark)
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailDisclosure1
                annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = detailDisclosure2

                if currentAnnotation.title == "Empty" {
                    annotationView.draggable = true
                }

                return annotationView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didAddAnnotationViews views: [MKAnnotationView]) {

        for annotationView in views {
            if (annotationView.annotation is SpecimenAnnotation) {
                annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -500)
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                    annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
                    }, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if let specimenAnnotation =  annotationView.annotation as? SpecimenAnnotation {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("NewEntry", sender: specimenAnnotation)

        }
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChangeDragState newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        if newState == .Ending {
            view.dragState = .None
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, if `dequeue` in `viewForAnnotation` succeeded, before you return the `annotationView`, you must set the `annotation` of the view to be the `annotation` that was passed to this method. You should also perform any other necessary configuration that might change for the new `annotation` (e.g. setting the `draggable` on the basis of the `title`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the accessory to the left and right accessories, to see which was selected:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if let specimenAnnotation = annotationView.annotation as? SpecimenAnnotation {
        if control == annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView {
            // left
        } else if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            // right
        } else {
            fatalError("Unknown accessory")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Rob I will try this. So do I add in the next line to segue after the line starting 'if control'?  i.e. inserting the lines performSegueWithIdentifier("LeftDetail", sender: specimenAnnotation) after that line and before the 'else if'

Comment: You put one `performSegueWithIdentifier` where it says `// left` and the other where it says `// right`.

Comment: Thank you Rob!  (apologies for my delay replying. Had a few bugs to battle before I was able to try this out). It worked well!